# Hello, how would I send a Folder of Pictures through Javamail?

Tags: processing, jakarta-mail

I am able to send a picture through JavaMail, but now I would like to send a folder of pictures. Now I know what some may be saying, just link the path to Processing. Yes, I have done that, but the problem is that it says that the Access is somehow denied. I am using saveFrame() to save the frames of the sketch, and I would like to send those to my email. Now I can except any answer, whether if it is about: How do I fix the error of the "Access Denied" to the folder with all my photos, or you can answer: If I am doing saveframe like this: "saveFrame("picture-#####.png")j, and those pound signs become random numbers, when I am linking the file to javamail can I just link it to: "picture-#####.png" and it will automatically find all of those? Thanks in advance, I know I may speak a little confusingly.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Kevin Workman! Hello! Nice to see you in a different environment. Anyways, I already solved the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your "access denied" problem.

You can add many attachments to a message to send lots of pictures, or you can put all the pictures in a zip file and send the zip file as a single attachment.

If you're still stuck, you need to provide more details about what you're doing and what's failing.

Comment: Hello, so instead of using a normal folder, I need to use a zipped folder! Okay I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: Right, you can't attach a folder, but you can create a zip file and attach the zip file.

Comment: @TechWiz77 also keep in mind the size of the attachment (as different mail servers support different sizes)